# PayPal Express Checkout - The field Shipping Address Postal Code is required

Tags: paypal, opencart

I enabled the PayPal Express checkout module on Opencart 3.0 and filled out all the fields on the checkout page but it doesn't go to the PayPal page. All it does is to reload and state the shipping address postal code is required. Why?

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: please feel free to share some code with us.Not every one know what you have done until he looks at it,